# Running a program after system startup directlly from the linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to run my application directly from the linux kernel(without usage of cron or something like that). If I change ./init/init.c, it runs too early:

```
$ dmesg 

...
[    0.605657] TEST!!!
...
```

My idea is to launch an application after successful user login, but I can't find an appropriate function to use.

Answer (score 0):

You're jumping to conclusions. Why do you want the kernel to do anything if you have the whole userspace running already? (you want it on user login)

Have a look at one of the standard mechanisms for this (depending on what's available in your system):

1. systemd user sessions
2. .profile / .xinit files for users
3. For advanced scenarios, maybe even socket activation for services.